# Is there a notion of "graph of bundles" analogous to a graph of groups?

Tags: ct.category-theory, vector-bundles, geometric-group-theory, fibre-bundles

Since the notion of a graph of groups relies mostly on the pushout, can we construct graphs of objects in some other category, say, vector bundles?     If this is the case and we have a "fundamental bundle" (analogous to the fundamental group of the graph of groups, a colimit of vertex bundles(?)) would this yield any extra information about the vector bundle?

Comment: Example:  Given a manifold $M$, a vector bundle $E$ (or sheaf), and an open cover $(U_\alpha )$, one has the $\check{C}$ech complex associated to the cover.  Each simplex has a bundle given by the restriction of the original bundle $E$ to the intersection corresponding to that simplex.

I might have to $\check{C}$ech the details a little more, but I think this is an example.